# Reference SVG file to SVG object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

My question is how can I refer to a SVG file with a SVG object created with javascript ? What I'm trying to do so far does not seem to work

```js
  var svg = document.getElementById("svg");
   svg.setAttribute('width', '2048');
   svg.setAttribute('height', '784'); 

  var background = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
   background.setAttribute('width', '2048');
   background.setAttribute('height', '784');
   background.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', 'myimg.svg');
   background.setAttribute('x', '0');
   background.setAttribute('y', '0'); 

svg.appendChild(background);
```

```css
svg
{
 border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <svg id="svg"></svg>  
</body>
```

Comment: what are you expecting that code to do?

Comment: I want it to print out my image in the html page with size of  thee image (2048x784)

Comment: you need to add the element you created to the DOM ... something like `document.body.appendChild(background);` - or wherever you need it to go

Comment: I did that, but the problem is, if I use `var background = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");`, the image show up but with "svg", the image did not. I want to interact with the image as a svg, not as an image so just to show it is not enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this code

```
var svgDocument, svg;
var obj=document.createElement('object');
obj.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    svgDocument = this.contentDocument;
    svg = svgDocument.querySelector('svg');
});
obj.data = 'myimg.svg';
document.body.appendChild(obj);
```

You create an `object` with data set to your svg file. onload, the "root" element (the svg element) can be obtained as shown

Note: you can't access contentDocument until the svg has loaded.

Comment: Is there anyway I can create an object with something like `var background = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "object");` then load in the data by `background.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'data', 'myimg.svg');` ? Maybe I get the syntax wrong but will this possible ? And also, will that object behave like an SVG ?

Comment: @user4075830 `objectElement` is an HTML element. Just use `document.createElement('object');` and `obj.setAttribute()`, no need for the namedspace version. Also, Jaromanda's example show you how to load an external svg document into an object and then access the loaded SVGDocument.

Comment: Why use svg namespace for a html element

Comment: @JaromandaX also, `svg` will reference the SVGDocument, not the documentElement (not the `<svg>`). Maybe this should be included in the answer

Comment: I would have used the `contentDocument` property as it avoids a call to a function but I guess it's minor issue. I hope OP will accept and upvote it.